# imagemagick crop images to specific aspect ratio?

Tags: imagemagick

Given an image, how do I use imagemagick to resize it to a specific aspect ratio? for example, to an aspect ratio of `2:1`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Two things to consider:

1. Simple resizing with or without aspect ratio conversion
2. Cropping with aspect ration conversion

I address each in turn:

**1. Simple resizing with or without aspect ratio conversion**

`imagemagick` by default will maintain the preexisting aspect ratio of an image during conversions. Using this test image:

[image]

which conveniently has the dimensions of 100x100 an attempt to resize to 300x150 with this syntax will silently *fail*:

```
convert test.png -resize 300x150 300_test.png
```

and will produce a *150x150* image:

[image]

To force `imagemagick`to actually produce your 2:1 aspect ratio image the following slightly different syntax is required:

```
convert test.png -resize 300x150\! distort.png
```

And this achieves a 2:1 aspect ratio, with distortion of the original image of course:

[image]

**2. Cropping with aspect ration conversion**

If you would prefer to simply and automatically crop an image to a specified aspect ratio the easiest way is to use one of [Fred's ImageMagick Scripts: 'Aspectcrop'](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/aspectcrop/index.php). Usage on our test image is simply:

```
./aspectcrop -a 2:1 test.png Fred_wins.png
```

and the resulting image has been successfully cropped to a 2:1 ratio:

[image]

The other option to be manipulated is `-g gravity` which defines which part of the image is used for cropping. The default is center, all options are:

1. center (c)
2. north (n)
3. south (s)
4. east (e)
5. west (w)
6. northwest (nw)
7. northeast (ne)
8. southwest, (sw)
9. southeast (se)

So to give an example of this using *north*:

```
./aspectcrop -a 2:1 -g n test.png north.png
```

The results are:

[image]

If you needed to use this script for a batch load of images in a single directory you could use a bash 'for' loop. First place the script correctly and set it to executable:

```
sudo mv aspectcrop /usr/local/bin
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/aspectcrop
```

This makes it a lot easier to use the script. Then run the 'for' loop from within a directory of images:

```
for i in *.png
do 
aspectcrop -a 2:1 -g n "$i" "${i%.png}_cropped.png"
done
```

This loop can be varied according to the type of input and output files, different locations etc. You could also produce a similar syntax that will search recursively for images. Lots of possibilities...

I think that is all pretty cool :)

**References:**

- [Imagemagick: Resize or Scaling (General Techniques)](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/)
- [Fred's ImageMagick Scripts: 'Aspectcrop'](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/aspectcrop/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script for all jpg in folder to check 4:3 aspect.

```
#!/bin/sh

EXTENSION="*.jpg"

for file in $EXTENSION
do
        currAspect=$(identify -format "%[fx:w/h]" "$file")
        roundFloat=$(printf '%.*f\n' 3 "$currAspect")

        if [ $roundFloat != 1.333 ]
                then
                        echo "name: $file aspect: $currAspect rounded: $roundFl$
                fi
done
```